# Is it possible to compress the packet between asp.net and sql server r2

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, compression

Is it possible to compress the data transfer between the asp.net and sql server r2 . I know about packet size in sql server using SinglePage Allocator and MultiPage Allocator

```
Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;"
        + "Integrated Security=SSPI;Packet Size=512"
```

The above is a SinglePage Allocator. I have to know whether it is possible to reduce the data transfer when i save a form details to the sql server using asp.net(c#) and sql serverr2

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Above, you are asking whether it's possible to compress the network traffic. In a comment to an answer below, it seems like you're asking whether it's possible to compress the database file. Those are very different problems.

Comment: @BenThul I am asking how to compress the data between the application and server

Comment: Then the answer below is pretty much what you have to do. At that point, it's not a SQL Server issue anymore, but more what are you doing on your network layer.

Answer (score 0):

No, compression is not supported by SQL server natively.  There are options, you can tunnel traffic through a VPN with compression enabled or setup a web service on SQL server that exposes the data you need access to.  Most web services and clients support gzip compression and you will benefit from this.  Alternatively, there are some commercial options that will support compression of SQL data.

See this post for more details:
[Possible to compress SQL Server network traffic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2453908/possible-to-compress-sql-server-network-traffic)

Comment: so it is a big procedure to compress the file