# How data is managed from SQL Server to .NET application

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have very generic question regarding how data is transfer between SQL Server and a C# application. When we request some data from SQL Server from a C# app:

1. Is data secured?
2. Is data compressed? If yes, what is compression algo? How much data will be compress (% wise)?
3. Can we provide custom algo to secure or compress the data?

Comment: See [this other SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2453908/possible-to-compress-sql-server-network-traffic) that handles part of your question

Comment: @marc_s - there is also an answer of first question regarding security :)